# How to make calibrateCamera return just only 4 distCoeffs

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, 3d-reconstruction

the definition of calibrateCamera is:
CV_EXPORTS_W double calibrateCamera( InputArrayOfArrays objectPoints,
InputArrayOfArrays imagePoints, 
Size imageSize,
InputOutputArray cameraMatrix,
 InputOutputArray distCoeffs,
 OutputArrayOfArrays rvecs, OutputArrayOfArrays tvecs,
int flags = 0, 
TermCriteria criteria = TermCriteria(TermCriteria::COUNT + TermCriteria::EPS, 30, DBL_EPSILON) );

some these params :

@param distCoeffs Output vector of distortion coefficients
\f$(k_1, k_2, p_1, p_2[, k_3[, k_4, k_5, k_6],[s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4]])\f$ of 4, 5, 8 or 12 elements.

@param flags Different flags that may be zero or a combination of the following values:
-   **CV_CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL** Coefficients k4, k5, and k6 are enabled. To provide the backward compatibility, this extra flag should be explicitly specified to make the calibration function use the rational model and return 8 coefficients. If the flag is not set, the function computes and returns only 5 distortion coefficients.

as we see, the fuction calibrateCamera(...)return a 5*1  distCoeffs Mat,but because of k_3,it will undistort too much, I really dont need k_3,as if the k_3 is used for Fisheye Lens, and cvCalibrateCamera2(...) just return a 4*1  distCoeffs Mat

so what can I do to deal with calibrateCamera? I search a lot but still have no ideas.

[image: 1.jpg]

[image: 1undistort.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the flag cv::CALIB_FIX_K3. Here is the disCoeffs with and without this flag calculated in my test.

```
{0.456533, 0.377582, 0.0250243, -0.0100882,  0}
{0.425909, 0.169672, 0.0236827, -0.00983692, 0.249512}
```

But the result undistort image in my test doesn't make any difference.